# Orca Script not setting File version details to the executables

Tags: powerbuilder, orca, powerbuilder-build-deploy

I am using the following snippet for PB automated build.
All the properties are available in the Executable other than File Version and it still refers to 1.0.0.1

```
set exeinfo property fileversion "2.2.0.2"
set exeinfo property productversion "2.2.0.2"
set exeinfo property companyname "XXXXX"
set exeinfo property description "XXXXXX"
set exeinfo property copyright "Copyright © XXXXX Corporation 2016"
set exeinfo property productname "XXXXX"
set exeinfo property fileversionnum "2.2.0.2"
set exeinfo property productversionnum "2.2.0.2"
```

Could any one help in Building with proper File version.
PB version : 12.5

Answer (score 0):

From this [online post](https://maonet.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/orcascript-setting-version-number-into-exe/), and contrary to the documentation (but PB's doc has some errors), it might help to pass the `FileVersionNum` parameter as 4 numbers separated by coma `,` instead of decimal point `.`